# Working in Internet explorer but didnt in firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, firefox-addon, rest-client

I am trying to access a rest webservice through the internet explorer. I am getting method not allowing, but when i am trying to access from the rest client of the firefox i am getting block by proxy.

Since ie doesnt have rest client i tried where the url is access by desktop and whether firewall is blocking it.

Where as in the internet explore there is only automatic script configuration which  i enable it in the firefox also. is there anything other than this  i am missing

Answer (score 2):

check whether are any configuration script required to performed the operation.
check wherther it is one way ssl or two way ssl